# Postscript printing from codeblocks - very odd output

Tags: ubuntu, colors, codeblocks, postscript

I would like to print some code from code::blocks 12.11 on an Ubuntu 13.04 machine. All other printing seems to be fine but the output to the printer and file (postscipt) has strangely misaligned colours. The text all seems to be there but different coloured text is moved / scaled / overwritten making it unusable (sadly I don't have the reputation to include an image) so I've uploaded one at [picpaste](http://picpaste.com/c__bOddOutput-WOtAkFrO.jpg).

Any ideas - I don't know whether this is CB, ubuntu or ..?

Thank you

Comment: Can you upload a sample of the postscript code somewhere, like pastebin?

Comment: I've updated my question to include a link to an image.

Comment: Having a picture is better than not having one. But still, we can only speculate without seeing the postscript file itself. A postscript file is a text file. You should be able to paste the text directly into the question.

Comment: Even when there's nearly 13000 lines?

Comment: Is that just for 1-page of printed source-code?

Comment: Yes - ~100 lines of code produced ~13000 lines of postscript

Comment: That *is* quite a lot. But I really think we need to see it. Pastebin?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AsmqRx8T
Here you go - thanks luser droog

Answer (score 0):

Wow. There's a *lot* of nonsense in that file. Reencoding the same font over and over and over again. `0 0 translate`. `1.00000000 1.00000000 scale`. I'm not sure whether to blame wxWindows PostScript renderer or code::blocks, but that's some **bad** postscript code.

I made a work-around, but it's not really a *fix*. And if any of the responsible parties are reading this, DO NOT DO THIS and consider it fixed. It's broken.

That said, inserting this code just after `%%BeginProlog` appears to give much better results. It seems that the placement of text is using the wrong size for the space character, so shrinking all the fonts a little bit makes it look ok.

```
/shrinkfont {
    dup dup findfont dup length dict begin {
        1 index /FID ne {
            1 index /FontMatrix ne {
                def
            }{
                .0008 exch .0008 exch
                dup length array copy
                scale def
            } ifelse
        } { pop pop } ifelse
    } forall
    currentdict end definefont pop pop
} def 
/Courier shrinkfont
/Courier-Bold shrinkfont
/Courier-Oblique shrinkfont
```

Packaged as an AWK script:

```
#shrinkfont.awk
!/%%BeginProlog/{print}
/%%BeginProlog/{
print "%%BeginProlog"
print "    % modification by shrinkfont.awk"
print "    /shrinkfont {"
print "        dup dup findfont dup length dict begin"
print "        {"
print "            1 index /FID ne {"
print "                1 index /FontMatrix ne {"
print "                    def"
print "                }{"
print "                    .0008 exch .0008 exch"
print "                    dup length array copy"
print "                    scale def"
print "                } ifelse"
print "            } { pop pop } ifelse"
print "        } forall"
print "        currentdict end definefont pop pop"
print "    } def"
print "    /Courier shrinkfont"
print "    /Courier-Bold shrinkfont"
print "    /Courier-Oblique shrinkfont"
print "    % end modification"
}
```

Invocation:

```
awk -f shrinkfonts.awk postscripttest.txt > postscripttest.ps
```

Comment: I'm impressed you can make head or tail of all that and even more impressed that you can do something about it. You say that this could be wxWindows or Code::blocks. Even though I may be out-of-date in wanting to have a hard copy from time-to-time, I would have expected an outcry from the c::b community if this was universal (which there doesn't seem to be). This suggests to me that there's something wrong with my setup -I'll look into my installation - thank you for narrowing it down. I'll report back shortly.

Comment: I am a bit of a postscript fanatic. :) Line 488 is where it starts printing *line 5*, where the first problems occur. Line 636 is where it starts printing the text for that line. You can see that it's doing explicit moves for each differently-colored portion of the text. So it's the calculation for those moves that's going wrong. It could be related to missing fonts or missing font metrics. IMO it's foolish to have written it with those explicit moves at all, since the normal use of `show` would automatically leave the currentpoint in the appropriate place. But since they're there, ...

Comment: ... it's vital that the rendering module have access to the correct font metrics so it can calculate the string widths accurately.